# Sort array of custom objects alphabetically as per search string rest object should come at last

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting, swift3

Everyone I have a array of following `File` object

```
File{
var displayName: String? // eg detail.txt, abc.doc
var size: Int?
..
}
```

say, I have a array of this file object

```
let arrayOfFile = [f1,f2,f3,f4.....f1000];
```

These file objects are getting display in a `UITableView` over a screen. There are a search option, where user can search files...
Now the problem is, when user type something into `UISearchBar` I need to sort `arrayOfFile` array in such a way that the `File` object which contains search string (**within name**) comes first (**all in alphabetic sorted order**) and other files which doesn't contains search string **within name** come at the end.

this is what I have tried so far...

```
self.dataArray =  self.searchDataSource.sorted(by: { ( f1, f2) -> Bool in
    if f1.displayName.lowercased().strContains(text) && f2.displayName.lowercased().strContains(text){
                            if f1.displayName.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare(f2.displayName) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending{
                                return true;
                            }
                            else if f1.displayName.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare(f2.displayName) == ComparisonResult.orderedSame{
                                return true;
                            }
                            else if f1.displayName.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare(f2.displayName) == ComparisonResult.orderedDescending{
                                return false;
                            }
                            else{
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                        else if f1.displayName.lowercased().strContains(text){
                            return  true
                        }else if f2.displayName.lowercased().strContains(text){
                            return true
                        }
                        else{
                            return false
                        }
                       })
```

Comment: In pseudo code: `if (f1...contains(text) && !f2...contains(text)){return true}else if (!f1...contains(text) && f2...contains(text)){return false} else {return f1.displayName.caseInsensitiveCompare(f2.diplayName) != .orderedAscending }` or something like that? Logic similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45674976/sort-nsarray-custom-object-on-multiple-properties/45689734#45689734 where "is of custom type" is equivalent to "contains(text)".

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this would be to make your ‘File’ class conform to ‘comparable’. 
Then call sort method on the File array.

Comment: Interesting. Can you elaborate?